# Gravity, orbiting bodies and Newton’s second law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

As I understand it an object travelling in a circular motion is undergoing a centripetal ‘force’. As Newton’s second law of motion, put in simple terms states that a moving object will tend to continue in a straight direction and keep a constant speed unless another force is applied.

Whereas the Earth travels around the sun and as described by Einstein general relativity it is ‘falling into the sun’s gravitational well. I believe Einstein did not describe gravity as a force, rather that a large body like the sun is bending spacetime. So, if I follow this correctly the Earth is just following a naturally curved path created by the suns warping of spacetime.

Does this explain why we do not experience any centripetal force acting on us or other objects on the surface of the Earth, as we travel at 67,000mph in a circular motion around the sun? Also If we were in a spaceship outside the gravitational well of any large bodies such as the sun and travelling at 67,000mph with the same trajectory as our current orbit around the sun, would we be able to ‘feel’ or measure a centripetal ‘force‘ acting on us and the spaceship?

Comment: Hi Harvey, have you tried to estimate how big the centripetal force would be?

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question. You are mixing Newtonian mechanics and General Relativity concepts. Moreover, a gravitational well is not something with a well definite border.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, unfortunately I don’t know how to make that calculation. I guess what I am really after is whether the effect would be negligible if travelling at that speed and turning in an arc relative to the Earths orbit, in a space where there is no gravitational interference. Likewise confirmation that whilst the Earth is in the Sun’s orbit there will be no centripetal force acting on the Earth ?

Comment: Hi GiorgioP - Well, yes in a way I am mixing the two concepts. Does this not happen in the real world ? and in the real world which concept will prevail ?

Comment: There is no such thing "which concept will prevail". Both of them can explain your observation accurately. But we can apply Newtonian Gravity in everyday concepts like this because it makes very less difference in such cases.

Comment: GR has nothing to do with the reason why we don't feel centripetal force orbiting around the sun. The reason is that the force is tiny. See the similar question linked above.